# Run add class on different elements concurrently jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to slide a menu bar from the left and at the same time slide the page to the right using CSS and jquery. I can do the sliding no problem but what is happening is the body slides left, then once that is complete the menu slides out

JS

```
$('body').toggleClass('slide-left', '');
$('.mid-side-menu').toggleClass('slide-out', '');
```

CSS

```
.slide-left {
  position: fixed;
  right: 300px;
  transition: right 0.5s;
}

.slide-out {
  transition: right 0.5s;
  right: 0px;
}
```

How do I run the two commands at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish what you want with your current implementation. You would need to add the same class to both items, but have the class act differently based on what it is applied to.

For example:

## jQuery

```
$('.mid-side-menu, body').toggleClass('slide-out', '');
```

## CSS

```
body.slide-out {
  position: fixed;
  right: 300px;
  transition: right 0.5s;
}
.mid-side-menu.slide-out {
  transition: right 0.5s;
  right: 0px;
}
```